# a recursive function using memoization

Tags: programming, recursion, memoization

I have looked at a lot of these cases, e.g. [Can one identify the design patterns of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/25150#25150) and the included ones.

My trimmed example, here establishing the 'initial conditions' (where the zp___List symbol has 3 underscores) and utilizes only 2 external global functions, `B` and `K`;

```
wgn[0,0,zp___List]:=0;
wgn[0,1,zp___List]:=0;
wgn[0,2,zp___List]:=B;
wgn[g_Integer/;g<0,npo_Integer,zp___List]:=0;
wgn[g_Integer,npo_Integer/;npo<0,zp___List]:=0;
```

and then the recursion (I changed a double sum to a `Sum @@ Flatten[Table[`);

```
wgn[g_Integer /; g >= 0, npo_Integer?Positive, zp___List] := 
  wgn[g, npo, zp] =
   (
    Sum[
     (
      Module[{z, tmp1, tmp1b, tmp2, asso, T1},

        tmp1 = Rest[Drop[zp, -Length[zp]/2]];

       tmp1b = Rest[Drop[zp, Length[zp]/2]];

       tmp2 = Subsets[tmp1, {0, npo - 1}];

       asso = AssociationThread[tmp1, tmp1b];               

       T1 = Table[{tmp2[[o]], Complement[tmp1, tmp2[[o]]]}, {o, 1, 
          Length[tmp2]}];

       (
          wgn[g - 1, npo + 1, Flatten[List[Join[
               {z, -z},
               Rest[Drop[zp, -Length[zp]/2]],
               {j, j},
               Rest[Drop[zp, Length[zp]/2]]]
              ]]]

           +

           Total[Flatten[Table[

              wgn[h, 1 + Length[T1[[wc]][[1]]], 
                Flatten[
                 List[Join[{z}, T1[[wc]][[1]], {j}, 
                   asso /@ T1[[wc]][[1]]]]]]
               *

               wgn[g - h, 1 + Length[T1[[wc]][[2]]], 
                Flatten[
                 List[Join[{-z}, T1[[wc]][[2]], {j}, 
                   asso /@ T1[[wc]][[2]]]]]]
              , {h, 0, g}, {wc, 1, Length[T1]}]]]

          )
        , {z, 0}]
       ]
      )
     , {j, 1, 1}]
    );
```

`tmp1 & tmp1b` split the 3rd argument into variables and numbers and there is an association  - `asso` - between them. So the 2nd variable and 2nd number are correlated. `tmp2` calculates all the Subsets of $$z_1,\ldots,z_n$$ and then `T1` constructs pairs where one element of `tmp2` at a time is paired with its set-complement, i.e. to make $$A \cup B = \{1,\ldots,n\}$$, and then summed over in the double sum.

I call it like,

```
wgn[2,1,{z01,1}]
```

and for this case expect

```
wgn[1,2,{z,-z} + w[0,1,{z,j}]*w[2,1,{-z,j}] + w[1,1,{z,j}]*w[1,1,{-z,j}] + w[2,1,{z,j}]*w[0,1,{-z,j}]
```

where `j` would be 1 by the double sum... I mean the `Sum @@ Flatten[Table[...`. Then the 2 'initial conditions' would fill in the rest, giving (after killing the `w[0,1,{...}]` terms,

```
wgn[1,2,{z,-z} + w[1,1,{z,j}]*w[1,1,{-z,j}]
```

Then the recursion would start again, and the `w[1,1,{z01,1}]` terms would be replaced by,

```
~ Res[K*w[0,2,{z,-z,j,j}],{z$2,0}]
```

and the `wgn[1,2,{z,-z}]` term replaced by some other terms.

Problem now is that I have the **recursion limit problem** but can't figure out why, especially since my initial conditions should take care of any runaway negative valued terms.

(One thing, the 2nd variable, `npo` is half the length of the list `zp`.)

Here is the formula if it is at all needed,

$$w_{g,n+1}^{i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_n}(z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_n) \sim \sum_{j=1}^N Res_{z->0} K * \left( w_{g-1,n+2}^{j,j,i_1,\ldots,i_n}(z,-z,z_1,\ldots,z_n) + \sum_{A\cup B=\{1,\ldots,n\}} \sum_{h=0}^g w_{h,1+|A|}^{j,\vec{i_A}}(z,\vec{z_A}) * w_{g-h,1+|B|}^{j,\vec{i_B}}(-z,\vec{z_B}) \right)$$

I define `npo := n+1`. The function `Res` is just residue but returning zero isn't too helpful ;)

Comment: It doesn't look like you're handling `wnnng[0, 0, ___]`. Not sure if you need that, just thought it was pertinent.

Comment: My guess is this is never bottoming out: `wgn[h, 1 + Length[T1[[wc]][[1]]] ...]`

Comment: hhmmm... I added the `w[0,0,{...}]` but it didn't help. I also assume my function definition, , would at least return an answer with an unevaluated `wgn[0,0,{...}]` because of `npo_Integer /; npo > 0`   That term you show... it will quit recursion if it is `w[0,1,{}]` or `w[0,2,{..}]`

Comment: Also I think by constructing a MWE from this you'd find the error. Try making this the most minimal code you can that still causes the issue.

Comment: I'll think it over but I cannot see how it could get any more MWE than it is...

Comment: Also instead of `Sum@@` you want `Total`. By `Sum@@` you meant `Plus@@` which is just `Total`.

Comment: Get rid of every external function. Replace `zp` with `{}` always since it has no bearing on the bottoming out. Drop the `Res` call and just like add up the two arguments. Things like that. There are *many* extraneous things here and I think they're making it hard for you to find the error.

Comment: Okay, I'll look that over... and yes, I meant to write `Plus @@ Flatten[Table[`, probably need the `Flatten` even with `Total`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more minimal example that shows the error:

```
tooLong // Clear
tooLong[0, 1, zp___List] := 0;
tooLong[0, 2, zp___List] := 0;
tooLong[g_Integer?(# < 0 &), npo_Integer, zp___List] := 0;
tooLong[g_Integer, npo_Integer?(# < 0 &), zp___List] := 0;
tooLong[g_Integer?(# >= 0 &), npo_Integer?Positive, zp___List] :=

 tooLong[g, npo, zp] =
  tooLong[g - 1, npo + 1, {}] +
   Total@
    Flatten[
     Table[
      tooLong[h, 1]*
       tooLong[g - h, 1],
      {h, 0, g}
      ]
     ]
```

From here it's clear the issue is the line `tooLong[g - h, 1]`. That will never bottom out since `g-h` will always be greater than `0` and `1` will never be less than or equal to `0`.

You need to handle that case too.

Comment: Aahhhh I wasn't sure what you meant by getting rid of zp with {}.... I'll have to digest your amazingly succinct result....

Comment: @nate the big thing is that `Length` will never be non-zero and you’ll always have at least one `Subset` if you allow the empty set.

Comment: Yes, I notice that even if `tmp` and `tmp1b` are empty, the length of `T1` is still 1. I've tried playing around with the 2nd argument of Subsets[] but it is tricky for me.

Comment: actually.... if the `Table[tooLong[h,1]*tooLong[g-h,1],{h,0,g}]` runs from `h=0` to `h=g`, how can it not be zero?

Comment: If `g` is non zero you recurse infinitely. `g-0==g`.

Comment: oh, I think I see what you are saying. The thing is, if `g` does not get decremented it will turn out that the other term in the pair is a `tooLong[0,1,{}]`, which by the initial condition is killed to zero. Does it matter which term Mathematica come across first?

Comment: @nate not as you have it in your code. You have `wgn[g - h, 1 + Length[T1[[wc]][[2]]], ...]`. You're starting with `g>0`. So that term will never bottom out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89959/discussion-between-nate-and-b3m2a1).